# Need advice on what technologies to use for mobile app

Tags: mobile, project

I need to develop a mobile application as school work and I need some advice on what the best approach to this would be. It can be HTML5 based, a native Android app or anything else as long as it's primarily made for mobile platforms. It needs to make use of a database, have a login function (can be login through Facebook) and interaction between users.

I barely have any experience with server-side scripting, web development or mobile app development. I'm quite good at general Java programming though, and I know a bit of HTML/CSS (no JavaScript).

So what I'm wondering is: what technologies should I invest time in learning in order to develop this app within 8 weeks or so? Ease of learning is the top priority. It's definitely a plus if it's a multi-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of learning I would recommend HTML 5 and JavaScript to make a Phonegap application. Phonegap is faster to develop than a native Android app, because you can test with a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different reasons to create an app: maybe you see a need for a business app, maybe you just have a great idea. But regardless of the reason, you still have to start at the beginning.
Native mobile apps

Native mobile apps are likely what come to mind when you think of apps. A native app is one that is developed to be ‘native’ to a specific platform: Apple’s iOS, Google’s Android, Windows Phone or (decreasingly) BlackBerry OS.

The principal advantage of a native app is that it optimizes the user experience; the app will operate more quickly because it’s been designed specifically for that platform.

The principal disadvantage? If you wish to build and launch your app on more than one platform (e.g. a chat messenger) you almost need to start each one from scratch. Let’s look at each platform more closely.
Hybrid mobile apps

What makes an app a hybrid? A hybrid app can be installed on a device like a native app can, but it runs via a web browser. These apps are built using a language called HTML5.The reasons for this are simple—these hybrid apps are not as fast, reliable or smooth as native apps.

Web apps: Responsive websites switch to a different design when they are accessed from a mobile device. Adaptive web applications, on the other hand, adjusts to fit the different screen sizes of mobile devices. For these apps, the design doesn’t change. Web apps are built using the most popular programming languages, but they can’t use hardware on mobile devices or be sold in any app stores.

The fact is that most businesses use multi-platform mobile app formatting. They need to find solutions to develop cross-formatted apps. And though hybrid app development can be a complicated process, the end product is more popular with consumers and more marketable as a result. There are a wide variety of high-quality tools designed specifically for multi-platform use.